# Cors политика при fetch post запросе

Tags: vue.js, axios, fetch, cors

проблема состоит в том что при попытке отправить запрос на любой эндпоинт получаю в ответе Cors политику

Запрос хочу отправлять с помощью fetch (Пробывал через axios результат такой же)
Отправляю post вот так с Body FormData

```
  let url = this.url + 'get_tarif/'
  let body = new FormData()
  body.append('uid', '6919')
  body.append('gettarif', '1')
  let headers = {
  }
  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: body,
    cors: 'no-cors'
  }

  fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Гуглил достаточно много, пробывал `mode: 'cors'` а также `mode: 'same-origin'`

Просмотрел очень много материалов касающиеся cors политики но почти везде теория, зачем это нужно и для чего

Запросы в `postman` обрабатываются правильно, а также используя `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` запросы проходят

Также думал что проблема может быть в `http://` или `https://` разницы нет

Уже не знаю что пробывать, пните на правильный путь, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

В целях безопасности браузеры ограничивают cross-origin запросы, инициируемые скриптами. Например, XMLHttpRequest и Fetch API следуют политике одного источника (same-origin policy). Это значит, что web-приложения, использующие такие API, могут запрашивать HTTP-ресурсы только с того домена, с которого были загружены, пока не будут использованы CORS-заголовки.

Или другими словами Это сервер должен ответить с соответствующими заголовками.

почитайте [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня задача сейчас такова чтобы переписать приложение с кордовы на котором используються ajax запросы в vue и фетч или axios запросами, аяксы там работают нормально, постман я так понимаю работает с какимто исключением, + ранее я уже сталкивался с такой ошибкой, на сервисе сбора подписок, не буду писать какой, их много, и там была возможность добавить почтывай ящик с помощью обращения к апи через пост запрос, не нумаю что они бы как-то ограничивали если сами предлагают использовать апи, возможно, я что-то делаю не так

Comment: Добавил ссылку и картинку

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю